# Long Network Operations in component in react native

Tags: database, react-native, networking

i am trying to fetch data from database in a component and want to set data on component.  i've tried in **componentDidMount()** and **componentWillMount()**. but it is taking sometime to load data. i am newbie to react native and does not have any experience to please properly guide me where is best place to perform

**long network opertions.**.

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.__fetchDataFromDB();
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: "Firebase"
  };

  __fetchDataFromDB = () => {
    var usersRef = firebase.database().ref("/Users");

    usersRef.on("value", snap => {
      const result = [].concat(...Object.values(snap.val()).map(Object.values));

      this.setState({
        data: result
      });
    });
  };
```

thanks

Comment: your server-side data is?

Comment: which server you are using?

Comment: show your code snippet what you have tried so far! your question scope is too broad please shorten down to the specific problem!

Comment: firebase database

Comment: hmm in case of firebase ! you should do first is to engage the data! using GraphQl server to get the data there and send it to you as response till then wait by using loading view etc!

Comment: and if you want to fetch data directly from firebase like the one you are doing you should open the loaderView and make the user wait!

Comment: am i doing it right in componentWillMount() ?

Comment: component did mount!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```js
if (this.state.isLoading === true) {
            return (
                <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                   
                    <ActivityIndicator size={ Platform.OS=='android'? 90:'large'} color="#DE0400" />


                </View>
            )
        }
```

When your data fetching is complete setState isLoading to false. And it's better to be in **componentDidMount()**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: null,
    loading: false,
  };

  fetchDataFromDB = () => {
    const usersRef = firebase.database().ref('/Users');

    usersRef.on('value', (snap) => {
      const result = [].concat(...Object.values(snap.val()).map(Object.values));

      this.setState({
        data: result,
        loading: false,
      });
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    this.fetchDataFromDB();
  }

  render() {
      const { loading, data } = this.state;

      if (loading) return <ActivityIndicator />;

      if (!data) return null;

      return (
          <View>
              {/* render your data here */}
          </View>
      );
  }
}
```